# Add a shared variable to Tframe

Tags: delphi, tframe

Software is Delphi 10.2 on Windows 10

Is there an easy way to create a custom override Tframe without creating a new component based on it ?

I have several different frames designed which have common variables.

So I tried a trick I have seen before...

```
unit FrameExUnit;

interface

uses Forms,classes, ChromeTabs,ChrometabsClasses;

Type
 Tframe=class(Forms.Tframe)
   Tab:tchrometab;
 end;

implementation

end.
```

and put FrameExUnit in the uses clause of all the different frame designs.

I have used this trick for creating custom forms and I have another component (AMsplitter) which works as well, but I can't get it to work with Tframe.

The designer seems to be happy, but because these frames are created dynamically at runtime, a bunch of errors occur in the inherited create event because it can't see the inherited properties of Tframe.

I know I must be doing something silly, Is there a simple way to add variables to Tframe ?

Comment: Why don't you just use a common base class?

Comment: @David Well I did try creating TFrameEx=class(Tframe) but it had the same issues. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @David I also tried republishing all the properties it was complaining were missing, which worked to a certain extent until I got one "OldcreateOrder" which is not even in the Tframe class. No idea how to get around that one.

Comment: This is too confusing. I happily use a common base class.

Comment: I think I have found a smoking gun. I used debug DCUs and traced into the constructor. I have a CreateEx constructor which call the inherited Tframe.Create contructor and it fails the ClassType <> TFrame test.

Comment: You should be adding the variable in a different public section, not into where the streaming system tries to read from the dfm. And no published properties either.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just store your extra data in the Tag property?

Comment: I found this, https://wiert.me/2009/07/22/delphi-frames-as-visual-components-changing-your-inheritance/   which explains a few things. Looks like Tframe is broken as far as inheritance goes.

Comment: @AndyK: that is a 9 year old article, AFAICT.

Comment: @AndyK: plain frame inheritance works fine, if you do it through the IDE (because that also modifies the .dfm). If you manually modify the .pas file, it won't work (neither should form inheritance). So don't fool the IDE and all is well. Or modify the .dfm manually too. The latter bears the risk you can do it wrong.

Comment: @Rudy Yes you are correct. The mistake was to not create a new frame from the IDE as the simple class declaration does not not link a form resource. However when you have existing frames which need to be derived from the inherited frame, you still have to manually doctor the form in text mode to make it all work correctly.

Comment: @AndyK: I think someone could write a simple expert for that, although it is not often necessary, so there won't be a big demand.